# How to Tag multiple values in rows to a single column?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have muliple products tagged to same ID , I want to show the ID once with the products in the single column separated by '/'.

eg. If 123 has A and B in separate rows then output should be 1 A/B in different columns.

```
select
d.*, 
case when d.col = 'A' AND d.loan_class = 'B'
then 'A/B'
else 'NA'
end name
From tab D
where id = '1'
Group By ....;
```

Answer (score 2):

Isn't that `LISTAGG`?

```
select id, 
       listagg(product, '/') within group (order by null) list_of_products
from your_table
group by id
```